# How to exit <nuxt-child> when using sub routes

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

So I have three pages in my app. In my folder structure, I have something like this:

```
/verify
---complete.vue
---business.vue
---personal.vue
verify.vue
```

so basically `verify.vue` has a `<nuxt-child>` component that deals with my `business.vue` and `personal.vue`. What I want to happen is `complete.vue` even inside the parent route of `/verify/complete`, will be having a different layout/page template.

Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem with extendRoutes in nuxt.config.js. What this does is it adds a custom route without using the folder structure. So when the /verify/complete is hit, it will resolve the component.

```
router: {
  middleware: ['auth'],
  base: '/beta/',
  extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
    routes.push({
      name: 'verify-complete',
      path: '/account/verify/complete',
      component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/account/verify-complete.vue')
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works for me. I had same kind of problem with nested route which needed a different layout out of <Nuxt-child/> scope.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to track current route through `$route.fullPath`, and if i'ts `/verify/complete`, then change layout appropriately. Lets consider this markup:

`verify.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <h1 v-if="$route.fullPath === '/verify/complete'">Complete</h1>
    <h1 v-else>Business or Personal</h1>
    <nuxt-child></nuxt-child>
  <section>
</template>
```

If it's more complicated thah changing some block, tha you should define different pages components, and load them appropriately throug `<component :is="COMPONENT_NAME">`:

`verify.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <component :is="COMPONENT_NAME"></component>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this is not what I want to achieve. I already posted my answer.